# Replaced batteries in CyberPower 1350AVR UPS, now it resets every 5 seconds

Tags: ups

I have no idea what is causing this, and the CyberPower website doesn't even list this particular issue in their list of "all beep codes".

All I did was take out the old batteries and replace them.  Pretty simple and straightforward, except this keeps happening and I don't know why.

I have disconnected the battery, held power down for 30 seconds, and reconnected it, but no change.

Video demonstration of issue:

https://youtu.be/btT0Xo9U6xE

Comment: Did you use the correct OEM batteries (not third party)? Are there hidden connections?  My connections between batteries are part way in on my APC unit.

Comment: They are 3rd party batteries that are very standard to replace for this model (Specifically from Mighty Max).  No hidden connections, the swap itself was pretty routine.  Here's a video that shows this exact model swapping batteries and this is exactly what I did:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GtDQzniJ1s

Comment: You can remove them and check the voltage. No load voltage is usually not informative. You can then call the battery supplier and see if you can get replacement batteries. The assumption is that the UPS hardware is good.

Comment: UPS was good until the batteries died a couple weeks ago (about 5 years old so they had a good run).  My sense is that if the batteries were just plain bad, it wouldn't power up at all.  The fact that it does, then does this 5-second thing makes me think there's something else going on.

Comment: Hard to say. If the unit was under load when the  batteries died, there could have been some damage. You may need to get the unit serviced. There is no practical way to determine whether new batteries or the unit itself is the issue

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  Hadn't considered that.  I'll contact CP and see what they say.

Comment: So my answer about checking battery voltage - was that (and removing the batteries) helpful?

Comment: Well not directly in that I didn't check their voltage, though ultimately doing so would've revealed the same issue with the terminals having come loose.  It was realizing that the reason it was looking was that it was on mains power, and that if I disconnected mains power it didn't come up at all, that made me think the batteries had to have become disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, according to Cyberpower this sounded like a POST failure, but since the UPS was plugged into mains power, it just kept trying forever.

So I took everything out one more time, and it looked like the terminals on one battery had wiggled loose. I reconnected them again being very very careful they stayed connected this time, put it all back together, and voila - all is good!